# Use Same DrawerLayout and ActionBar In All Activities In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In MainActivity, I've created a DrawerLayout and ActionBar. Is there any way to use that same Drawer and ActionBar in other activities without writing the same code again? Here's the code I'm using:

Main.xml:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextColor="#FFF"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            >
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/homepage_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            ></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav"
        android:layout_width="277dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"></com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Main Java (I've Removed The Extra Code [Non Drawer-Actionbar Code]):

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
TextView json;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private RequestQueue mqueue;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        setuptools();
        setUpToolbar();
    }
    private void setUpToolbar()
    {
         drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
         toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name) ;
         drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
         actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.right_menu,menu);
        final MenuItem awesomeMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.notification_iconmain);
        View awesomeActionView = awesomeMenuItem.getActionView();
        awesomeActionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onOptionsItemSelected(awesomeMenuItem);
            }
        });
        final TextView not_num = (TextView) menu.findItem(R.id.notification_iconmain).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.hotlist_hot);
        String username = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String server_url = "https://google.com/api/notifications.php?username="+username;
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, server_url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject notification_numbers = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String final_num = notification_numbers.getString("notifications");
                                if(final_num.equals("0")){
                                }else{
                                    not_num.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    not_num.setText(final_num);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }
        );
        mqueue.add(request);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.notification_iconmain){
            Intent intent_noti = new Intent(this, NotificationsPage.class);
            this.startActivity(intent_noti);
        }
        if(id == R.id.user_icon){
            Intent intent_user = new Intent(this, Profile_Page.class);
            this.startActivity(intent_user);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What It Does:

It creates a slider drawer, an action bar with the right side menu, and displays the notification count on Bell Icon, and each item has its custom on-click event.

Now, how I can use the same drawer, action bar without writing the code again and again in each activity.

Comment: you can use fragments instead of activities and add the DrawerLayout and ActionBar to parent  activity

Comment: What if I want to use Activities

Comment: you have to Repeat it

Comment: As Noureldien Mohamed mentioned above, the fragment is the best solution.